# How can I achieve a Quartz look using concrete for a bar top?

Tags: concrete, design, technique

I want to make my own concrete bar top but I would like it to have a bit of a sparkle like quartz has. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [terazzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrazzo):

[image]

The basic process is:

- add your 'sparkle' substance as aggregate (glass is a typical option)
- pour concrete
- after concrete sets, you use a diamond grinder to expose the top layer of aggregate

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the aggregate. There are a lot of options depending on the look you're going for. Abalone shell is popular, and monochromatic glass chips could work well too. What you do is add a lot of these aggregates to your concrete mix (appropriately colored, and including performance-enhancing additives such as metakaolin or ground granulated blast furnace slag). Then you raise the aggregate by floating the surface while it's still wet. Once it's dry and hard and at least a week old (preferably a month old), you grind the surface down a millimeter or two to expose more of the aggregate. Then polish and seal with sodium silicate and bob's your uncle.

Comment: Never heard ["bob's your uncle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob's_your_uncle)... Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add white rock on the surface of your cement & tamp it in then finish this will give some color.
Exposed aggregate uses this technique if they want white, black brown rock not just plain cement. Bags of colored rock can be found at many home improvement stores.